# Need Simple way to access XML in VB.Net - Pain with Linq-to-Xml

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, linq-to-xml

Dim myXDoc As XDocument = _

I want to access this in a simple way in VB.Net - Like:

Dim Integer SizeXStr = CInt(MyZDoc.Cameras(1).Camera_Desc.@SizeX) ' where (1) is an index

Why isn't this implemented in VB.Net?  Better yet, type the values with
a Schema and eliminate the conversion.  Is this so hard?

How do I access, in a simple way, data in XML - this would be VERY VERY useful!

I have been using Query to try to get the values - when I use MsgBox() to display
results, they display, but my main Windows Form is Trashed - changed colors, etc.
The system has Bugs.

Instead, I have to create an elaborate structure of arrays of objects and read the
XML line-by-line and do the same for saving - this is the dark ages.

Art

Comment: With the exception of `Dim Integer SizeXStr` (which should read `Dim SizeXStr As Integer`) your code looks fine. But the answer you're looking for could be anything - despite your long description, I can't really figure out how to help you. Are you have problems with the index value? Are you using `.ToString` for your queries to display in the MsgBox? What exactly is the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of your problem but you're probably missing a .ToString() in there somewhere that MsgBox is implicitly calling for you. Turn `Option Explicit` and `Option Strict` on fix those (and other) problems. Anyway Given the following variable(VB 2008):

```
    Dim myXDoc = <cameras>
                     <camera>
                         <description SizeX="10"/>
                     </camera>
                     <camera>
                         <description SizeX="12"/>
                     </camera>
                 </cameras>
```

You can get an integer using:

```
Dim SizeX = Integer.Parse(myXDoc.<camera>(0).<description>.@SizeX)
```

Answer (score 0):

[XPathExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathexpression(v=VS.100).aspx) and/or [XPathNavigator](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301111)?